# Where is the location for the default program icon?

Tags: windows, icons

Where is the location for the default program icon? It looks like this:

[image: Default Program Icon]

Also, if it's located in a .dll file, what index is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\user32.dll,0
%SystemRoot%\System32\user32.dll,5
```

Also, check this file for the Default Programs icon with a green tick.

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\sud.dll
```

[image]

(Tested on Windows 10)

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to know what is the difference between `user32.dll,0` and `user32.dll,5`?

Comment: No difference between the two in size or quality. You can even see many duplicate sets of icons in `shell32.dll`. Not sure why it's like that.